# PHP uploading files image only

Tags: php

I am not able upload my image file to server, using XAMMP phpmyadmin and apache services. I'm wondering where I did wrong.
I have to use this kind of security code to prevent any extension upload that can exploit by hacker.
It just shows that the files is "Your image was not uploaded" as an error code.
Not sure if it is because I didn't specify the root of the website? If yes, how can I specify?

```
<html>
<head> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$target_dir = '/uploads/';
$target_dir1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadedname=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$uploadedname_temp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$uploaded_ext=substr($uploadedname_temp,strrpos($uploadedname_temp,'.')+1);
$uploaded_size=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if (($uploaded_ext == "jpg" || $uploaded_ext == "JPG" || $uploaded_ext == "jpeg" || $uploaded_ext == "JPEG") && ($uploaded_size < 1000000)){ 
                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir1)) { 

                    echo '<pre>'; 
                    echo 'Your image was not uploaded.'; 
                    echo '</pre>'; 

                  } else { 

                    echo '<pre>'; 
                    echo $target_dir1. ' succesfully uploaded!'; 
                    echo '</pre>'; 

                    } 
            } 

            else{ 

                echo '<pre>'; 
                echo 'Your image was not uploaded.'; 
                echo '</pre>'; 

            }   
}

}

?>



</head>
<body>




<form action="uploadfiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"it just show that the files is Your image was not uploaded"* - You're outputting that exact message more than once in your code.  Which `if` condition is resulting in `false`?  What are the inputs to that condition?  What specifically is failing?

Comment: there are easier ways to get the extention of a filename than `$uploaded_ext=substr($uploadedname_temp,strrpos($uploadedname_temp,'.')+1);` - checkout [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: @David it's this statement return Your image was not uploaded                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir1)) { 

                    echo '<pre>'; 
                    echo 'Your image was not uploaded.'; 
                    echo '</pre>';

Comment: @jeff oh thanks will check it out . new to php haha

Comment: @TehWinSam: Are there any warnings in the PHP logs?  What are the runtime values of the file names you're passing to `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: @David i think is this ? [Mon Oct 22 19:22:27.955296 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 4572:tid 1548] [client 192.168.0.1:54845] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant DocumentRoot - assumed 'DocumentRoot' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\\temp\\htdocs\\uploadfiles.php on line 10, referer: http://192.168.0.11:82/uploadfiles.php  .

Comment: @David i upload an image 12345.jpg with 130kb files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code. it is working properly. As there was issue with `$uploaded_size` you have not declared size variable and used that.

```
    <html>
    <head> 

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $target_dir = realpath(__DIR__) . '/uploads/';
    $target_dir1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadedname=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $uploadedname_temp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $uploaded_size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
    $uploaded_ext=substr($uploadedname_temp,strrpos($uploadedname_temp,'.')+1);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
         if (($uploaded_ext == "jpg" || $uploaded_ext == "JPG" || $uploaded_ext == "jpeg" || $uploaded_ext == "JPEG") && ($uploaded_size < 1000000)){ 
                    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_dir1)) { 

                        echo '<pre>'; 
                        echo 'Your image was not uploaded.'; 
                        echo '</pre>'; 

                      } else { 

                        echo '<pre>'; 
                        echo $target_dir1. ' succesfully uploaded!'; 
                        echo '</pre>'; 

                        } 
                } 

                else{ 

                    echo '<pre>'; 
                    echo 'Your image was not uploaded.'; 
                    echo '</pre>'; 

                }   
    }

    }

    ?>



    </head>
    <body>




    <form action="uploadfiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When you upload any file, that file get uploaded in `tmp` folder of your server with some temporary name. So you have to move that file from `tmp` folder to your required folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to move the file by it's original file name. However, when it gets uploaded, there is a `['tmp_name']`. When you `move_uploaded_file()`, you need to refer to the tmp name.

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir1)) {
```

to

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_dir1)) {
```

Comment: oh , meaning that when files get uploaded the files will be kind of rename to a temporary files name and it will point to the temporary files name to upload it ?

Comment: Correct. So move the temp file from the temp folder to your destination. Also look out, you have said `$target_dir = '/uploads/';`. That's on the root of your hard drive, should it not be in the project folder somewhere?